# Ace editor - SublimeText package control equivalent?

Tags: sublimetext, cloud9-ide

I just started using Cloud9 with Ace editor after a long time usage of the wonderful Sublime text editor.

Is there something like PackageControl for Cloud9/Ace?
And if not, is there any way to install packages individually?
I really miss having snippets like yard documentation for ruby methods.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

The extension manager for cloud9 is still in alpha http://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/v0.1/docs/getting-started-with-cloud9-plugins so there are no installable plugins yet.
However if there is a sublime plugin with snippets it should be easy to modify it to work with cloud9, you should create an issue on their sdk repository https://github.com/c9/core or comment in https://github.com/c9/core/issues/25

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mix of `sshfs`, your own terminal, and an EC2 instance that sleeps on idle to create your own "Cloud9" functionality by just running a single script that starts the server if needed, mounts the filesytem, and puts you into an ssh session all at once.

My recent blog post outlines step-by-step instructions:
http://zulrang.com/2018/03/cloud9-with-local-editor-and-terminal/